# Timed-out lock in java

Tags: java, locking, timeout

I am looking for mechanism which will help me to implement following pattern (pseudocode):

```
TimeoutLock lock = new TimeoutLock();
while(condition) {

    prepare();

    lock.enter(); //cannot enter until specified lock timeout elapses
    execute();
    lock.lockFor(2 minutes);

    finish();
}
```

I need to limit invocations to **execute** to occur no more often, than some specified interval (for example, two minutes), but I do not want to block **prepare** or **execute** if it is not necessary. I am wondering if java supports any locking mechanism, which 'vanishes' after some time. Requirement is that, of course, lock does not pass through even if it's entered by the same thread, which locked it.

I was thinking about solution involving semaphore and **TimerTask**, or calculating deadline by myself and sleeping for superfluous time, but I wonder if something like this is already available.

Thanks

Comment: You should **definitely** not design this to block a thread for the timeout period. The approach with scheduling is a must.

Comment: I would use a wrapper around a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor, or a DelayQueue.

Comment: Scheduling would be much better, I agree. But could you please briefly explain why blocking a thread (any thread? or just a main thread?) is a Bad Thing?

Answer (score 2):

The below will do 
basically you have a semphore which will only let you access if there is a permit available, I this case zero permits. So it will try for 2000 seconds before finally giving up
->

```
Semaphore s = new Semaphore(0);
Object lock = new Object();
 synchronized(lock)
{
execute();
s.tryAcquire(2,TimeUnit.Minutes)
}
```

`Thread.sleep` is a lame and low level way of doing it. Not recommended

Answer (score 1):

No need for a special class:

```
synchronized(lock) {
   execute();
   Thread.sleep(120 * 1000)
}
```

Comment: when we leave synchronized block lock gets released

Answer (score 1):

[As Marko says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518120/timed-out-lock-in-java#comment18505663_13518120), you very likely want to do this by handing the work off to a scheduler of some sort, rather than blocking the thread.

But if you do want to do this, i would suggest that you do it by recording a timestamp on exiting the critical section, and having entering threads wait for a period after that to pass. Something like:

```
public class TimeoutLock {

    private boolean held;
    private long available;

    public void enter() throws InterruptedException {
        acquire();
        long pause;
        while ((pause = available - System.currentTimeMillis()) > 0L) {
            Thread.sleep(pause);
        }
    }

    private synchronized void acquire() throws InterruptedException {
        while (held) {
            wait();
        }
        held = true;
    }

    public synchronized void lockFor(long period) {
        held = false;
        available = System.currentTimeMillis() + period;
        notify();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the sleep

```
sleep(1000);
```